# How to enforce constraints in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

```
 > CREATE TABLE student(
-> student_id INT(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
-> first_name VARCHAR(10),
-> last_name VARCHAR(10)
-> );

 > CREATE TABLE course(
-> course_id CHAR(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
-> course_name VARCHAR(50),
-> student_id INT(2) NOT NULL,
-> CONSTRAINT student_student_id_fk
-> FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
-> REFERENCES student(student_id)
-> );
```

Thats how i created two tables namely student and course. Then i entered data in the student table. But when i enter some invalid data in the course table, it doesn't gives me any error.
For example:
       VALUES('A1','SUB 1',34);
gets the entry in the course table even if there is no primary key '34' in the student table.

Also, i can delete records in the student table, even if there is referential integrity.
So, how can enforce the constraints?

Comment: I'm happy to help you, but it would be nice once in a while for you to click on the tick next to answers when they help you to acknowledge the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to change your storage engine to InnoDB which supports the constraints.

For old MyISAM tables, you will have to use triggers on BOTH sides to enforce an FK relationship

Some links for self-help

- http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-enforcing-foreign-keys.html
- http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers

Create your tables like this

```
 > CREATE TABLE student(
-> student_id INT(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
-> first_name VARCHAR(10),
-> last_name VARCHAR(10)
-> ) ENGINE = INNODB;

 > CREATE TABLE course(
-> course_id CHAR(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
-> course_name VARCHAR(50),
-> student_id INT(2) NOT NULL,
-> CONSTRAINT student_student_id_fk
-> FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
-> REFERENCES student(student_id)
-> ) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Comment: I really cannot understand the 'storage engine to InnoDB', Sorry, i am a beginner.

Comment: @Gopal - MySQL comes with a variety of storage engines that actually manage the data. You can specify a different engine with each table. If you don't specify an engine, it will use the default engine, which is MyISAM. It is fast for many things (which is why it is the default), but it does not support foreign key constraints like you want. The InnoDB engine does.

Comment: When i use the code SHOW CREATE TABLE course, I get this:           course | CREATE TABLE `course` (
     `course_id` char(5) NOT NULL,
     `course_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
     `student_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`course_id`),
      KEY `student_student_id_fk` (`student_id`)
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

Comment: So, yes, you are right, it uses MyISAM storage engine by default.

Answer (score 0):

For someone having the same problem, if you already created your table using MyISAM, you can change it to InnoDB using.

ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;